# Spring modelattribute not recognized anymore after ajax update

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, modelattribute

i´ve encountered the following issue several times:
I use a Controller to bind a dto to a html form (via thymeleaf). **Please note the model named "invoiceDto"**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/create"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String create(Locale locale, Model model) throws Exception {
            final String login = this.getAuthentication().getCurrentApplicationUser();
            if (login == null || login.isEmpty())
                throw new Exception(this.getMessageSource().getMessage("label.findError", null, locale));
    
            final Future<Setting> setting = settingService.findFirst();
            final Future<ApplicationUserContactProjection> applicationUserContactProjection = applicationUserService.findByLogin(login);
            while (!setting.isDone() && !applicationUserContactProjection.isDone()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            if (setting.get() == null || applicationUserContactProjection.get() == null)
                throw new Exception(this.getMessageSource().getMessage("label.error.findError",
                        null, locale));
    
            model.addAttribute("invoiceDto", new InvoiceDto(setting.get(), applicationUserContactProjection.get()));
            model.addAttribute("message", this.getMessageSource().getMessage("label.navigation.invoiceCreation", null, locale));
            return "invoice/create";
    }
```

I have a html form (thymeleaf generated) where i use the above Java pojo dto with the given modelattribute name to fill my Input fields. This is an excerpt of it. **The important part is the div with the id of "invoiceLineItems" where thymeleaf replaces its child div with a lineItems Fragment:**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/invoice/newinvoice}" th:object="${invoiceDto}" role="form" method="post"
              class="form-signin" id="editInvoiceForm"
              accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div id="invoiceLineItems"><div th:replace="invoice/items :: lineItems"></div></form>
```

The fragement contains the following stuff - an excerpt of it:

```
<td>
                    <input type="text"
                           th:field="*{items[__${index.index}__].lineItemTotalPrice}"
                           readonly
                           class="form-control" disabled
                           id="lineItemTotalPrice"/>
                </td>
```

Excerpt of the given pojo:

```
public class InvoiceDto implements Serializable {
        private Invoice invoice;
        private List<LineItem> items;
```

I access the list like this:

```
th:field="*{items[__${index.index}__].lineItemTotalPrice}"
```

The Problem:
I can add items dynamically via Ajax. I serialize the whole form (for convenience reasons) and call a Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newlineitem"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newLineItem(@ModelAttribute("invoiceDto") InvoiceDto invoiceDto,
                              Model model)
            throws Exception {
    
        invoiceDto.addItem(new LineItem());
        final Future<InvoiceDto> calculatedInvoiceDto = invoiceService.calculateInvoice(invoiceDto);
        while (!calculatedInvoiceDto.isDone()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        model.addAttribute("invoiceDto", calculatedInvoiceDto.get());
        return "invoice/dynamicitems :: lineItems";
    }
```

As you can see, i let thymeleaf render a Special view, because after the Ajax success spring cannot set the modelattributes proper.
In short: After the Ajax Returns the partial view, the following will throw an exception:

```
th:field="*{items[__${index.index}__].lineItemTotalPrice}"
```

whereas this works - **note the prefixed invoiceDto:**

```
th:field="*{invoiceDto.items[__${index.index}__].lineItemTotalPrice}"
```

Question:
What´s wrong here?
Why do i have to prefix the name of the modelattribute after the partial Ajax update, whereas in the first run i don´t have to?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**
For my share it looks like the way that spring "forgets" the originally named form modelattribute "invoiceDto" if the page is partially updated by an ajax call (to another spring controller, modifying invoiceDto) through a partial thymeleaf html.

So after the controller returns the partial thymeleaf view i have to access its fields with prefixed "invoiceDto", as if there would be no invoiceDto attribute.

Thanks again for your help!

**UPDATE**
As there is no progress on this i have raised a thymeleaf issue:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/795

Nevertheless i think this is a spring issue, because i have the same results with JSP.

**Repository to comprehend this issue**
https://mygit.th-deg.de/tlang/thymefail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference object passed to Thymeleaf fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353628/reference-object-passed-to-thymeleaf-fragment)

Comment: @BrianClozel thank you for your suggestion. The tip does not work for me. Please see updates on the question. On one hand i have made a repository to be cloned and on the other hand i have raised a thymeleaf issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to use the `*{}` notation when there is no active object. When the ajax method returns just the "lineItems" fragment, Thymeleaf has no way of knowing that it belongs to a form with a `th:object` on it.

I guess the best solution is to return the whole form then, in js, extract the lineItems.
Or maybe just get rid of `th:object` altogether (convenient only when you want to show validation errors imho).

Comment: The strange thing is that i can use the `*{}` notation. After the ajax call (where i submit the whole form, which is materialized the right way by spring´s modelattribute type in the controller) the model variable is there (with the same key). After rendering the partial view i have to prefix the model´s name like so: `th:field="*{invoiceDto.items[__${index.index}__].lineItemTotalPrice}"`